# Asking agents to behave during a certain time period with the time extension

Tags: netlogo

I'm using the time extension in NetLogo to load in some daily temperature data. The turtles in my model have some procedures that relate to this temperature data. I can set up the temporal aspect as follows:

```
  set time-series time:ts-load "environmentTimeseries.txt"
  set start-time time:create "2018/01/01"
  set current-time time:anchor-to-ticks start-time 1.0 "day"
  time:anchor-schedule start-time 1.0 "day"
```

The turtles can interact with this temperature data:

```
set current-temp time:ts-get time-series current-time "temp"
  ask turtles [
set my-temp random-normal current-temp 1 ; my-temp is a turtles-own variable
]
```

What I would like to do now is have the turtles only perform this procedure during certain months of the year. Something like, `if month > 5 & < 7 [do procedure]`. Unfortunately, the scheduler in the time extension keeps crashing my model so I'm not sure that's an option.

Hope you can help

Comment: `if month > 5 & < 7` isn't legal NetLogo, but `if month > 5 and month < 7` is. but you might as well just say `if month = 6`, since that's the only number between 5 and 7. perhaps you actually mean `if month >= 5 and month <= 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I'm after in the [time documentation](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time). I can create a `turtles-own` variable called `my-month` and then apply the following line of code that allows the agents to keep tabs on the current month:

```
set my-month  time:get "month" current-time
```